# How to influence a command throughout the document?

Tags: fonts

I have a long document which includes quite a lot of `\textbf{...}` and `\textit{...}` even just in the middle of sentences. I would like to put something in the preamble in order to make every text that is bold or italic, a sans serif text. I need it to be reversible (that's why I don't want to change each of the hundreds of occurrences adding `\sffamily{...}`).

I already tried to use

```
\let\oldtextbf\textbf  
\renewcommand{\textbf}{\sffamily\oldtextbf}
\let\oldtextit\textit
\renewcommand{\textit}{\sffamily\oldtextit}
```

but this only produces sans serif from the first occurrence until the end of the document. What should I use to get back to normal font every time a bold or italic text ends?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeX already has the infrastructure to do it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textit}{\sffamily\slshape}

\begin{document}

Now is \textbf{the time} for \textit{all good} men...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the default definition of `\textbf` is

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
```

and that it's definitely *not* a good idea to redefine `\textbf` using `\renewcommand`, which would make fragile commands. With the above approach, that's reversed by simply commenting out the two lines, the commands `\textbf` and `\textit` remain robust.

However, the best would probably be defining personal commands to use instead of `\textbf` and `\textit`:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bfemph}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\itemph}{\sffamily\slshape}
%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bfemph}{\bfseries}
%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\itemph}{\itshape}
```

Switch the comments to use one version or the other and use `\bfemph` and `\itemph` in your document.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to define commands that will inherit the font family from the surrounding text, as many other markup languages do?

Comment: @Random832 Not really clear, I'm afraid. Can you explain?

Comment: nevermind, I think I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Random832 That's the (unconfigurable) default in TeX: if you want a font change, you need to tell it to change fonts. Also, as a note to OP, I would suggest using more meaningful names than `\bfemph` and `\itemph`. That doesn't give any indication to the reader about what those typographic patterns *mean*.